# finding and saving results from mongodb search in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, foreach, mongoose-schema

I have a model name blog and inside that model exists this:

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
image: String,
body: String,
author: {
  id: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "User"
  },
  username: String
 },comments: [
  {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "Comment"
  }
  ],
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

What i want is to search for the blogs that have the same author.username and print the to a ejs page with forEach but i have no idea how. To print all the blogs i use this:

```
blogs.forEach(function(blog){
//code that shows and styles the blogs
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "the same"? The same to specific one? Or To print all blogs, where at least 2 have the same author? Or something else?

Comment: I want to print all blogs that have the same author example all blogs written by admin

Answer (score 0):

For example you want to get all blogs with author `authorname`. Then your code would be like

```
let specificBlogs = blogs.filter((blog)=>blog.author.username === 'authorname')
```

Also you can ask mongoose for specific docs only:

```
BlogModel.find({ 'author.username': authorname }
```

Comment: Finally a correct answer! Thank you so much you helped me a lot!